# SQL Server 2012 Date DateTime datatypes: parameter-passing from .NET: silent casting?

Tags: .net, date, datetime, parameters, sql-server-2012

A stored proc in SQL Server 2012 is expecting a **Date** datatype

```
create proc foo
@invoicedate date
as
begin
end
```

EDIT: The app server-side uses Date whenever a time component is not relevant. For example, a diary, where only the year month and day are needed.

Client-side, the parameter in .NET is defined as follows:

```
// at this point in the code, caldate is an Object
// that can be cast to DateTime

SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter();
p2.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDbType.Date;
p2.ParameterName = "@invoicedate";
p2.Value = (DateTime) caldate;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
```

Does the .NET SqlClient data library automatically (silenty) strip the time-component from the parameter value client-side when the value in `caldate` is bound to the `.Value` property of parameter `p2`?

Comment: What happens when you test?

Comment: @Blam: I don't think testing could answer the question `Does the .NET SqlClient data library automatically (silently) strip the time-component from the parameter value client-side` because even if the code above works (which it does) it could be that the time-component is being stripped server-side.

Comment: Did you try printing p2.Value?

Comment: @Blam: p2.Value contains the full DateTime value with the time-component, though that does not provide an answer as the stripping of the time-component, if it does occur client-side and not server-side, could occur deeper inside the "black box" where one cannot step through Microsoft's code, AFAIK.

Comment: Really you think the client is silently stripping data where one cannot step through making debugging a nightmare?

Comment: @Blam -- An analogy: the .NET data libraries report "concurrency error" when an update query affects zero records, even if no concurrency violation has occurred, so some datatype coercion going on "behind the scenes" does not seem far-fetched. But I am asking, not saying.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you'd want to instead use `DateTime` or `SmallDateTime`, according to [this info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) `Date` stores only date.

Comment: actually in this app in certain tables I want to store only the date in the database, ignoring the time component, so for that one does choose the Data datatype as distinct from the DateTime datatype in SQL Server. Question is, is the CLR DateTime cast silently to Date without a time component?